# htacces rules for mobile and desktop site

Tags: htaccess, php, mod-rewrite

I  have a site that stores an `index.php` for desktop computers and a `mobile.php` for mobile devices. Both files are in the same directory (say `/var/www`). As default the user accesses `index.php` and if his screen width is less than 900 px he gets redirected to `mobile.php`.

To load various content within `index.php` or `mobile.php` there are menu links passing one or two php variables which state the directory where the content is stored.

for example, if I want to display the location I load the page from `./Contact/Location/Location.php` into `index.php`.

The problem is here that `.htaccess` does not know if I'm working with the default or with the mobile site, so the following rules do not work together:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?id=$1&id2=$2 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ mobile.php?id=$1&id2=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Is there a way to make it working? The main advantage of having it like this is that I don't have to maintain two sites. The layout is made entirely within `mobile.php` and `index.php`.

Comment: Would you be up for different URLs for mobile and desktop like `/1234/5678/` for desktop and `/m/1234/5678/` for mobile?    You say that users are getting redirect do mobile, so then it would just be a matter of changing the code that does the redirect to use the `/m/` URLs.

Comment: This would seem a very bad way of doing it - why not incorporate the switching logic straight into php (by way if conditional includes?), or better yet use CSS to render the site appropriately per device.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930431/mod-rewrite-env-variables#930452 for how to use environment variables in Apache config so you can select the rewrite rule on the variable in .htaccess - but yuk.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the mobile and desktop URLs different to resolve this ambiguity. Perhaps with an `/m/` (mobile) and/or `/d/` (desktop) prefix?

For example, `/m/Contact/Location/` for your mobile site and the default `/Contact/Location/` for the desktop site. However, since there is a strong preference for "mobile-first" these days, maybe this should be `/d/` for desktop and no prefix for mobile?

> To load various content within `index.php` or `mobile.php` there are **menu links passing one or two php variables which state the directory where the content is stored**.

To be honest, when I read this I assumed you were already differentiating the mobile/desktop URLs in someway? I guess not.

You need to allow users to manually switch between desktop and mobile. You could perhaps store this user preference in a cookie/session variable (although that's not strictly necessary if the URLs are different).

You could rewrite the URL based solely on a mobile/desktop cookie (readable from `.htaccess`), however, search engines generally don't crawl with cookies (Google does not) so this will likely create problems with indexing.

> As default the user accesses `index.php` and if his screen width is less than 900 px he gets redirected to `mobile.php`

How do you handle search engine crawling currently? If you don't change the URL then I imagine Google could be redirected on every page request when searching using a mobile user-agent?

(*Aside:* "less than 900 px" - I assume that's CSS px, not actual screen pixels?)

Have you considered an *entirely responsive* design instead? One URL for both mobile and desktop. `index.php` for both mobile and desktop.